# How can i select a datetime as ddMMyy, so a two-digit year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime-format

I'm replacing my C# code for performance reasons with a sql query:

```
CreatedAt.ToString("ddMMyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

returns the creation-date as `140115`(for today). Simple enough in C#, but how do i get this in T-SQL?

I have tried:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), ChargeArrival.CreatedAt, 103), '/', '')
```

which is  almost correctly, but the year  has four digits instead of two, so `14012015` instead of `140115`.

Comment: I'm not convinced this will perform any better. Data type conversion is not free in SQL Server, either.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: it's not the date conversion that is part of the optimization but the replacement of LINQ-To-SQL where the object contains complex fields which are initialized by  other  database queries. Now i'm using a view which contains all relevant fields. It took 20 seconds to select 100 rows(load 100 objects), now only a fraction of a second.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear, it sounded like the efficiency problem was simply applying the formatting in C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the [docs for `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) state, use `103` if you want the century and `3` if you dont:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), ChargeArrival.CreatedAt, 3), '/', '')
```

Comment: Thank you. Iwas missing the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this also

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), ChargeArrival.CreatedAt, 5), '-', '')
```